# Why a number which is in (-1,0) raised to infinity is 0?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, infinity, indeterminate-forms

I hope it's not a duplicate but I've been searching about this problem for some time on this site and I couldn't find anything. My problem is why a number $\in(-1,0)$ raised to $\infty$ is $0$. For example let's take
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \left(\frac{-1}{2}\right)^n$$ 
Which is equivalent to
$$\left(\frac{-1}{2}\right)^\infty=(-1)^\infty\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^\infty=0(-1)^\infty$$
But if a sequence converges all its subsequences converge to the same limit.
And $(-1)^{2n}$ is a subsequence of $(-1)^n$ that converges to $1$ when $(-1)^{2n + 1}$ is a subsequence of $(-1)^n$ that converges to $-1$. So $(-1)^\infty$ does not exist. It remains that$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \left(\frac{-1}{2}\right)^n=0(DNE)$$

Comment: $\{(-1)^{2n}\}$ is *not* a subsequence of $\{(\frac 12)^n\}$.  Why do you think it is?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't explicit enough, when I refered to $(-1)^{2n}$ is a subsequence, I was meaning a subsequence of $-1$ not a subsequence of $(\frac{-1}{2})^n$ and that's available for "when $(-1)^{2n + 1}$ a subsequence that converges to $-1$" too. I was trying there to show why $(-1)^\infty$ doesn't exist. I'll edit.

Comment: I realized that later.  But if $a_n = b_n*c_n$ then $b_n$ converging is not a requirement for $a_n$ to converge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**:

Indeed $(-1)^\infty$ does not exists. To show that $(-1/2)^n$ goes to $0$, an idea is to show that:
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty}\left|\left(\frac{-1}{2} \right)^n-0 \right|=0$$

Comment: $$ \lim_{n \to \infty}\left|\left(\frac{-1}{2} \right)^n-0 \right|=\lim_{n \to \infty}\left|\left(\frac{-1}{2} \right)^n \right|=\lim_{n \to \infty}\left|\left(\frac{-1}{2} \right) \right|^n=\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(\frac{1}{2} \right) ^n=0$$ if I calculate your hint I reach your result but why did you put that 0 inside modulus?

Comment: It was to show that $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n=l$ is the same as $\lim_{n \to \infty} |a_n-l|=0$.

Comment: The $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n=l$ being the same with $\lim_{n \to \infty} |a_n-l|=0$ is a fact? And if it's a fact it's true in both ways, like the $\lim_{n \to \infty} |a_n-l|=0$ is the same with $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n=l$ ?

Comment: It is a fact and in a way it is the definition of $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n =l$ (think for example of the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of the limit).

Comment: The definition of $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n = L$ is that for any $\epsilon > 0$ there is an $N$ so that $n>N$ would mean $|a_n - L| < \epsilon$.  If $L=0$ then $|a_n|< \epsilon$ so if $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = 0$ then $\lim_{n\to\infty}|a_n|=0$.  And yes if $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = L$ then $\lim_{n\to\infty}(a_n-L)=0$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}|a_n-L|=0$

Answer (score 3):

If $\lim a_n = L$ exist and $a_n = b_n*c_n$ it does not follow that $\lim b_n$ exists and, indeed, we can *ALWAYS* find counter examples.  (Ex:  $\lim \frac 1{2^n} = 0$ but $\frac 1{2^n} = 2^n\frac 1{2^{2n}}$ but $\lim 2^n$ is not finite.)

So $\lim (\frac {-1}2)^n = (-1)^{n}*(\frac {1}2)^n$ but $\lim (-1)^n$ does not exist is utterly irrelevant.

===

What is true is that if $a_n = b_n*c_n$ and $\lim b_n$ and $\lim c_n$ both exist, then $\lim a_n = \lim b_n*\lim c_n$.

And if $a_n = b_n*c_n$ and $\lim a_n$ exists and $\lim c_n$ exists *AND* $\lim c_n \ne 0$ then $\lim c_n = \frac {\lim a_n}{\lim b_n}$.

Neither of those are the case here.

Comment: There are a lot of typos here: e.g. $2^n/2^{n+1}$, $(1/2)^2$, $c_n\not=0$

Comment: Ok, thanks for clarification. I understand now why I am not allowed to write $\lim a_n = \lim b_n*\lim c_n$ and why my approach was wrong. But it's still unclear for me why is $\lim_{n\to \infty} \left(\frac{-1}{2}\right)^n=0$ ?

Comment: @MuhammadLi  It isn't?  It's a basic N epsilon proof.  For any $1> \epsilon > 0$ then $\log_2 \epsilon < 0$.  let $N =-\log_2 \epsilon$ then if $n > N$ then $2^n > 2^{-\log_2 \epsilon}$ so $2^n > \frac 1\epsilon$ so $(\frac 12)^n = |(\frac {-1}{2})^n|<  \epsilon$.

Comment: I guess an easier proof.  For any $\epsilon$ then are $\epsilon > \frac 1n > \frac 1{2^n} >0$ so  $\epsilon > \frac 1n >( \frac {-1}{2})^n > -\frac 1n > -\epsilon$.  So for any $n>\frac 1{\epsilon}$ then $  |(\frac {-1}{2})^n|< \epsilon$ so $\lim_{n\to\infty}( \frac {-1}{2})^n=0$.

Answer (score 2):

Your assertion that $(\frac{-1}{2})^\infty=(-1)^\infty(\frac{1}{2})^\infty$ is wrong because the first limit on the right side does not exist. The limit of a product is only equal to the product of limits when all the limits exist.